# How to get checked RadioButtons according to IDs of dynamically generated RadioGroups

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group, android-radiogroup

I have dynamically generated multiple RadioGroups for questions which are fetched from the database and i have also assigned IDs to the RadioGroups serially.

Now, I want to get all checked RadioButtons from all the RadioGrouips so I may store them in the database.

How can I get all these RadioGroups and their checked RadioButtons pertaining to each RadioGroup ID?

Any attempt at a solution would be appreciated!

```
if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {

                String question = c.getString(1);
                String option1 = c.getString(2);
                String option2 = c.getString(3);
                String option3 = c.getString(4);

                // add text view
                qtxt = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
                counter4q += 1;
                qtxt.setId(counter4q);
                qtxt.setText(question);
                qtxt.setTextSize(15);
                qtxt.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black, null));
                ll.addView(qtxt);

                questions.add(qtxt.getText().toString());
                Log.d("arrayq",questions.toString());

                Log.d("question", qtxt.getText().toString());
                String qid = String.valueOf(counter4q);
                Log.d("questionid", qid);

                //create the RadioGroup
                rg = new RadioGroup(getApplicationContext());
                rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
                counter4rg += 1;
                rg.setId(counter4rg);

                rgIDs.add(String.valueOf(rg.getId()));
                Log.d("arrayrgid", rgIDs.toString());

                Log.d("rg", String.valueOf(rg.getId()));
                    String rgid = String.valueOf(counter4rg);
                Log.d("rgid", rgid);

                //add radio buttons
                o1 = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
                o2 = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());
                o3 = new RadioButton(getApplicationContext());

                counter4rb += 1;
                o1.setId(counter4rb);

                Log.d("o1", o1.getText().toString());
                String o1id = String.valueOf(counter4rb);
                Log.d("o1id", o1id);

                counter4rb += 1;
                o2.setId(counter4rb);

                Log.d("o2", o2.getText().toString());
                String o2id = String.valueOf(counter4rb);
                Log.d("o2id", o2id);

                counter4rb += 1;
                o3.setId(counter4rb);

                Log.d("o3", o3.getText().toString());
                String o3id = String.valueOf(counter4rb);
                Log.d("o3id", o3id);

                o1.setText(option1);
                o2.setText(option2);
                o3.setText(option3);

                o1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black, null));
                o2.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black, null));
                o3.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black, null));

                //the RadioButtons are added to the radioGroup instead of the layout
                rg.addView(o1);
                rg.addView(o2);
                rg.addView(o3);

                //you add the whole RadioGroup to the layout
                ll.addView(rg);

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
```

Comment: getId() only returns the Id of the last RadioGroup @NongthonbamTonthoi I need all the Ids

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
int o1_Id = o1.getId();
int o2_Id = o2.getId();
int o3_Id = o3.getId();
```

For getting all the ids of RadioGroups create a list:

```
List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
```

then add the ids:

```
 ids.add(counter4rg);
```

while getting :

```
    for( int i=0; i< ids.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(ids.get(i));
    }
```

To get checked RadioButtions:

```
     rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()            {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int selectedId) {
            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);
            //add to your list

        }
     });
```

Comment: What i need is the ID of all the generated RadioGroups

Comment: okay, now, how do i get the checked RadioButtons in all the RadioGroups?

Comment: Then create another list to store that